# How to find the decimal value of a character?

Tags: c

In C, how can I find the numerical value of a character.  For example the ASCII table says that the character 'a' has a decimal value of 97.

How can I print that?
Can I use "sizeof" function to find it?

Comment: What is "size" or "length" of a character? To print character code, just print it as normal number (for example, `%d` in `printf()`)

Comment: How the ASCII code is related to "length"? `printf("%d", 'a');` will print `97`.

Comment: Use `(int) c` given that `char c='a';`

Comment: whereas `printf("%zu", sizeof 'a');` is likely to print `4`.

Comment: Sanity check: do you really believe that `a` consumes 97 bytes of memory?

Comment: The size of a character is always 1.  The number of characters needed to print a character's value in decimal is `c > 99 ? 3 : (c > 9 ? 2 : 1)`

Comment: @stark the size of a `char` is always 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I wish I'd said that.

Comment: You're not asking about *wide characters* or *multibyte character sequences*, are you?

Answer (score 3):

The value of the expression `sizeof( char )` is always equal to 1. On the other hand, an expression like `sizeof( 'A' )` where an integer character constant is used as an operand of the `sizeof` operator is always equal to the value of the expression `sizeof( int )`.

If you want to output the internal representation of a character you can write

```
printf( "%c = %hhu\n", c, ( unsigned char )c );
```

where the variable `c` of the type `char` stores some character as for example `'A'`.

Comment: I assume `ll` was a typo. `s/ll/hh/`

Comment: @HAL9000 Thanks. It was indeed a typo.